# Auto-Proxy services with Consul Service Discovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul, netflix-zuul, service-discovery

I am attempting to move from Eureka to Consul for service discovery and am having an issue - my gateway service registers and my customer-service registers, but the gateway service will not route requests to the customer-service automatically.  Routes I have specifically defined in the gateway Controller that use Feign clients to route work fine, but before (with Eureka) I could make a request to any path like "/customer-service/blah" (where customer-service is the registered name) and the gateway would just forward the request on to the downstream microservice.

Here is my gateway bootstrap.yml (it's in bootstrap and not application because I am also using consul for config)

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-api
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        watch:
          wait-time: 30
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

Comment: can you give sample application.yml or application configuration in consul? I use consul and zuul for routing. zuul use as a gateway service. it work correctly.

Comment: consul can use same as eureka

Comment: Turnss out I had removed Zuul from my classpath.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this I think this help you to solve your problem..

This is my gateway bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
---

spring:
  profiles: default
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        prefix: config/dev/
        format: FILES
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
spring.profiles.active: dev
```

I use this dependency for gateway and for all applications

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

consul use as my configuration server. then I add consul to this configurations. configuration path is /config/dev/gateway.yml

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  ignoredServices: '*'
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 20000

  routes:
    customer-service:
        path: /customer/**
        serviceId: customer-service
        stripPrefix: false
        sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Gateway service spring boot application annotate like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    } // End main ()

}// End GatewayServiceApplication
```

if you make your application like this you can use routs your prefer way.

> sample consul configuration   [image]

Comment: So I accepted this because it pushed me in the right direction.  The real issue is, when I removed Eureka and Cloud-Config I had also, inadvertently, removed Zuul. <DOH!>  Added Zuul back as a dependency and BAM!  I did use your prefix config though, didn't know about that setting.